# WPF ComboBox with custom dropdown width

Tags: wpf, combobox, popup

How can I extend width of dropdown of a combo, like Run dialog:

[image]

Comment: By custom width do you mean to assign width explicitly or it should take width as per the longest item of the combo box?

Comment: @NareshRavlani explicitly, in code or XAML

Answer (score 8):

Popup is a part of ComboBox template ("PART_Popup"). Add a Style for `Popup` to combobox Resources and set appropriate width there.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Popup">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="1000"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

note also that there is a binding for Popup.MinWidth in template so you can't make it too small.

Comment: For others who land here, you can `<Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox},Path=ActualWidth}"/>` if you want it to be as wide as the ComboBox itself.