# WPF: How to Set the Width of a ComboBox's DropDown Correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm about to design a `DropDown` in WPF using XAML. If my text gets longer than the `Width` my `DropDown` element of the `ComboBox` is larger than the `TextBox` (as shown by the red arrow). Texts beeing to long are handled by an elllipsis (...).

Any ideas how to correct this?

[image]

This is my current XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FilterUiModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="UiModelTemplate">
            <ComboBox x:Name="FilterComboBox"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding FilterItem}"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                      Width="200">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=FilterComboBox}"
                                   Text="{Binding}" 
                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246876/wpf-combobox-with-custom-dropdown-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `Width` of the `Popup` to the `Width` of the `ComboBox` and set the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` attached property to `false` to hide any horizontal scrollbar:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FilterComboBox"
        ItemsSource="{StaticResource localTimeList}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding FilterItem}"
        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        Width="200">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Popup">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=FilterComboBox}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=FilterComboBox}"
                        Text="{Binding}" 
                        TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Special thanks for the hint to `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`. That made it really to a comprehensive solution!