# How to increase number of items shown in WPF ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, windows

My WPF ComboBox has a very tiny drop down area. Thus only three items and a scrollbar are shown. Is there a way to make the drop down area bigger, so that more items become visible?

[image]

Here's the XAML of the ComboBox:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
      <WrapPanel>
        <Image Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding StateImage}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Address}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
      </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

<ComboBox x:Name="CbxClients" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" Width="320" Height="24" IsEditable="False" />
```

PS: MaxDropDownHeight seems not to do anything. I already set it to 1000 or "Auto" with no effect.

Comment: maybe this method will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246876/wpf-combobox-with-custom-dropdown-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to modify the height of the `Popup` using an implicit `Style`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CbxClients" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" Width="320" Height="24" IsEditable="False">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Popup">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="1000"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```